# Transition to new url without reloading page with react-bootstrap-table onRowClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

Hello I was wondering if anyone here knew how to do something like this:

```
changeURL(event, row) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const itemId = row._id;
    this.context.router.transitionTo(`/item/${itemId}`)
}
```

inside a react-bootstrap-table onRowClick function:

```
render() {
    function showOSName(cell, row) {
      return cell.name;
    }

    function showBatteryCondition(cell, row) {
      return cell.condition;
    }

    var selectRowProp = {
      mode: "checkbox", 
      bgColor: "rgb(204, 230, 255)"
    };  

    var tableOptions = {
        sizePerPage: 5,
        deleteText: "✗ Delete Selected",
        paginationSize: 3,
        clearSearch: true,
        hideSizePerPage: true,
        onRowClick: function(row) {
            // here
        }
    };

    return (
        <BootstrapTable 
            className="react-bs-table"
            data={this.state.data.systems}
            striped={true}
            hover={true}
            pagination={true}
            selectRow={selectRowProp}
            deleteRow={true}
            multiColumnSearch={true}
            search={true}
            ignoreSinglePage={true}
            options={tableOptions}
            >
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="_id" isKey={true} dataAlign="center" 
            searchable={false}>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="model" dataAlign="center" 
            dataSort={true}>Model</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="serialnumber" dataAlign="center"
            searchable={false}>Serial Number</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="os" dataAlign="center" dataSort={true} 
            dataFormat={showOSName}>OS</TableHeaderColumn>
          <TableHeaderColumn dataField="battery" dataAlign="center" dataSort={true} 
            dataFormat={showBatteryCondition}>Battery Condition</TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>
    )
}
```

**EDIT**

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
(e) => this.changeURL(row, e);
```

inside:

```
onRowClick: function(row) {

}
```

I'm not too sure on how to handle the event inside an object's attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using ES6 arrow function to get around it:

```
onRowClick: row => {
    const systemId = row._id;
    this.context.router.transitionTo(`/system/${systemId}`);
}
```

Didn't need the event.